# How to use property of event args with async methods?

Tags: c#

How to use properties in async methods if we want to write it to a control.It throws an exception when trying to write without invoke.So I want to handle invoking problem in Counter class not in Form1. I have written an example for this problem. In this code TextBox.Text line throws cross thread exception.

```
internal class Form1 : Form        
{
    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Counter myCounter = new Counter(1000);
        myCounter.IndexValueChanged += myCounter_IndexValueChanged;
        myCounter.StartCountAsync();

    }

    void myCounter_IndexValueChanged(object sender, IndexValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.Index.ToString();
    }

}
class Counter
{
    public delegate void IndexValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, IndexValueChangedEventArgs e);
    public event IndexValueChangedEventHandler IndexValueChanged;

    int _maxNumber;
    int _index;
    public Counter(int maxNumber)
    {
        _maxNumber = maxNumber;
    }
    public async void StartCountAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _maxNumber; i++)
            {
                _index = i;
                if (IndexValueChanged != null)
                    IndexValueChanged(this, new IndexValueChangedEventArgs(_index));
                Thread.Sleep(100);

            }
        });
    }
}
class IndexValueChangedEventArgs
{
    int indexNum;
    public IndexValueChangedEventArgs(int index)
    {
        indexNum = index;
    }
    public int Index
    {
        get { return indexNum; }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the behaviour of your application to allow cross thread calls to modify your form elements:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Or, if people say that this is not recommended and not safe and is not proffessional,

you can use the [AsyncOperationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) in your Counter class. The WebClient.DownloadFileAsync method uses the same internally. This will ensure that the event handler will be called on the UI thread.

Here is your final Counter class which should be calling the delegate on the UI thread..

```
class Counter
{
    public delegate void IndexValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, IndexValueChangedEventArgs e);
    public event IndexValueChangedEventHandler IndexValueChanged;

    int _maxNumber;
    int _index;

    public Counter(int maxNumber)
    {
        _maxNumber = maxNumber;
    }

    public async void StartCountAsync()
    {
        AsyncOperation asyncCountOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _maxNumber; i++)
            {
                _index = i;
                asyncCountOperation.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(InvokeDelegate), _index);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
    }

    private void InvokeDelegate(object index)
    {
        if (IndexValueChanged != null)
        {
            IndexValueChanged(this, new IndexValueChangedEventArgs((int)index));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But people say that this way is not recommended, not safe and not professional. Is WebClient.DownloadFileAsync method using the same? Because it has the same progress property and can be used as e.CurrentProgress directly in Form class without Invoke.

Comment: I have looked up your advises for about 10 minutes but the code sample is so complicated. There is so many relationship between variables. I tried to copy the code to IDE but so many problems occured. If you can implement the solution to my code, it will help me so much. "Valla anlamadım hocam:)"

Comment: "You can change the behaviour of your application to allow cross thread calls" -- No, you can't. You can shut off the detection of bugs in your program, but they do remain bugs. Shutting off the detection just means you get silent subtle breakage that will become a huge pain to debug.

Comment: @hvd What is it that you are calling "bug"? Are you saying that, calling an instance method from a thread other than the thread the instance was created, a bug?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Yes. The one exception *could* be if you manually create some kind of synchronisation, but that's not what you're suggesting in this answer.

Comment: I suggested using the AsyncOperationManager.

Comment: And I implemented it into your Counter class @hasan-basri

Comment: @hvd, there is a very nice qoute from MLK. - Our scientific power has outrun our spiritual power. We have guided missiles and misguided men." Here, we are the men misguided by having made to believe this kind of standard behaviour (cross thread calls) to be a bug I think. But anyways. There is a suggested approach by the developer of the software (Microsoft) and we should follow it, there you have a point.

Comment: Actually, even Microsoft's own documentation on [`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx) points out that things break even if you have it at `false`: "When a thread other than the creating thread of a control tries to access one of that control's methods or properties, it often leads to unpredictable results." It continues by saying that setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `true` helps debug those problems, not that setting it to `false` fixes any problems.

Comment: It works perfect. I was looking for a solution like this for a long time. Thanks so much @Oguz.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a delegate on a ui thread you need a windows handle. I don't know why you want to do the invoke inside the Counter class, but the easiest way seems to me: give your Counter instance a reference to your Form and call the [Invoke-Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) on that reference. (Writing from my phone, so it's hard to add code sample, will edit tomorrow)

EDIT: but I really think it's the responsibility of the Form to check that it makes changes in the correct thread and therfore calls (Begin)Invoke itself.

EDIT: Here is your Counter class with the added "parent" reference:

```
class Counter
{
  public delegate void IndexValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, IndexValueChangedEventArgs e);
  public event IndexValueChangedEventHandler IndexValueChanged;

  int _maxNumber;
  int _index;
  Control _parent;

  public Counter(Control parent, int maxNumber)
  {
    _maxNumber = maxNumber;
    _parent = parent;
  }
  public async void StartCountAsync()
  {
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _maxNumber; i++)
        {
            _index = i;
            // introduce local variable for thread safety
            IndexValueChangedEventHandler handler = IndexValueChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                if (_parent == null || !_parent.InvokeRequired)
                    handler(this, new IndexValueChangedEventArgs(_index));
                else
                    // use BeginInvoke
                    _parent.BeginInvoke(handler, this, new IndexValueChangedEventArgs(_index));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And you use it in your button handler as this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter myCounter = new Counter(this, 1000);
    myCounter.IndexValueChanged += myCounter_IndexValueChanged;
    myCounter.StartCountAsync();

}
```

And it is better to use BeginInvoke in the Counter class, because Invoke would wait until the UI thread executed the delegate and so your Counter may count slower than expected (or your web client will use the network resources longer than needed). Hope this helped you.

EDIT: introduced local variable "handler". Otherwise it may be possible that the consumer deregistered the event after you null-checked it and it is null when you call it.

Comment: I want to tell why. I have written an HttpDownloader class as DLL. This works async and reports download progress via the event DownloadProgressChanged that contains "e.Progress" and for generally use I dont want the coder has to be use Invoke. I want to handle this problem as System.Net.WebClient's ProgressChanged event as I mentioned. It works async too, but there is no problem in using e.Progress property without Invoke. EDIT: If you add code,it will be more helpful for me to understand correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @hasan-basri, I upvoted Rene's answer becuase it would definitely solve the issue if you had that Counter class or similar for real. Since you did not give us the exact real use case and source code, how would you expect someone to help you with the exact solution? Isn't it a shame to waste someone's time like that? You should use AsyncOperationManager by the way..

Comment: Calling `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` from within the `myCounter_IndexValueChanged` callback is a much cleaner solution than passing a form to `Counter`. The latter ties the `Counter` code to a specific UI implementation, making it less reusable, while the former keeps UI-related code in the UI itself.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: I totally agree with you (see my first edit), but it was Hasan's explicit wish that the consumers of his class should not have to do this (maybe for some breaking change issue).  I have to admit that I don't know the AsyncOperationManager, so, Hasan, you may want to take another look there.

Comment: Since I have not enough reputation to comment @Oguz Ozgul, I write it here: the problem with CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls set to false is, it is a static property and effects your whole application. So you will have to add thread-safety checks in all your UI event handlers. And it is very likely that you will miss some important places. To make your UI work cleanly on one thread is the safer and recommended approach.

Comment: Dear @RenéVogt I agree with that. We are making development on a software platform provided by Microsoft and should behave as suggested by them. That's why I implemented the AsyncOperationManager into the Counter class in my answer.

Comment: I upvoted hvd's answer, 'cause it's obviously right as long as your "real" code does not need an extra thread at all.

Comment: Thanks.This way solves the problem in Counter class,  but it doesnt seem good to set a parent parameter at the download method.Using AsyncOperation is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, it doesn't make sense to me to use a background thread in the first place. Sure, if you call `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread, that's bad for obvious reasons, but you don't need to call `Thread.Sleep` to get an `async` method to wait.

```
public async void StartCountAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _maxNumber; i++)
    {
        _index = i;
        if (IndexValueChanged != null)
            IndexValueChanged(this, new IndexValueChangedEventArgs(_index));
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

If called from the UI thread, then after the delay, this method will continue execution on the UI thread, so the invocation of `IndexValueChanged` will just work.

Comment: I have just noticed that using `Thread.Sleep` is unnecessary.I just wanted to explaing myself with an example  Actually my real code doesn't contains `Thread.Sleep`. That's because of my inexperience. Sorry about this.